# True if either string is longer than X chars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an instance variable `@long_name` so that I can conditionally apply template styling if a user's first or last name is longer than X characters (in this case, 18).

```
 @long_name = current_user.first_name.length > 18
```

works just fine, but

```
 @long_name = (current_user.first_name.length || current_user.last_name.length) > 18
```

Doesn't work. What is the correct way to check "if A is longer than X or if B is longer than X"?

Comment: Your code just needs to match your description: `(current_user.first_name.length > 18) || (current_user.last_name.length > 18)`. Note that the expression `(exp1 || exp2)` in Ruby results in the value of `exp1` if it is "truthy", otherwise results in the value of `exp2`. So your current attempt effectively only tests one of the values (the first one that's non-zero in this case).

Comment: Right, I was hoping for an evaluator of "if A or B is greater than C", apparently in vain.

Comment: I think that might work in COBOL, but not Ruby. ;) The syntax you have unfortunately has a valid but different semantic meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way using `Enumerable#any?` and cuts down on the minimal duplication

```
[current_user.first_name,current_user.last_name].any?{ |name| name.length > 18}
```

Also since you want to use this as a conditional I would just make it a method

```
def long_name?(*names)
  names.any?{ |name| name.length > 18 }
end
```

Then you can call with `long_name?(current_user.first_name,current_user.last_name)`

This will also allow you to reuse this much easier in the event you need to change the comparison value from 18 to some other number. Now you need only change it once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `>18` in both halves of the expression:

`@long_name = (current_user.first_name.length > 18 || current_user.last_name.length > 18)`

In your answer, Ruby is trying to evaluate `current_user.first_name.length || current_user.last_name.length` before checking the `>18` part, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be using and array of lenghts

```
lenghts    = [current_user.first_name.length,
              current_user.last_name.length
             ]

@long_name = lenghts.max > 18
```